# Is expressjs able to serve files for many users at the same time?

Tags: node.js

Hello guys here I got a question and need a clearly answer because I have been thinking a whole day long. As you know nodejs is non-blocking by default (I usually work with expressjs) that means the new incoming connection have to wait ultil the current proccessing is done. The Question is. Is expressjs able to serve files for many users at the same time without scripting (I mean a standalone zip or sort of)

Comment: It means new incoming connections have to wait as long as *is required*, which is different.

Comment: What do you mean? I didn't quit understand